# PHP redirect to previous page pop-up form

Tags: php, redirect, popup

I saw here alot of Q&A about redirection but none that describes my question --> 
inside `index.php` i have **pop-up** login form. The server-side validation is done on a different file, `login_validation.php`. Now say validation failed - I want to return to the pop-up login form in the previous page, with the error messages inside the form.

Q: Is there a way to redirect to the same "state" to the previous page was before form submitted (I mean redirect back to `index.php` while the pop-up form is open, **without** javascript) ?

I know with javascript i can do it if I redirect back with GET/POST variable, and also that if the `login_validation.php` was on the same file as the login, It would also be solved, but I need to keep the described situation.

Comment: You can use ajax validation for server side and you can deside your login is valid or not and you can show hide your popup.

Comment: Thanks alot! it really seems as this is the only solution for my case.. I did it and it works.